# setting up variables and the results from a function within a string - all as a string in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to this and could use some assistance.

I have the following function and trying to add the result from the function into the strings below.
What am I missing to accomplish this?  I just want to have the results of the Function SrvName included in the strings below with no spaces on the two lines that are requiring the .txt as the ending.

```
Function SrvName {
   Get-WmiObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select-Object name | foreach { $_.name }
}

SrvName

$RPTLOCSpaceRpt = "D:\Svr_Win_Space_Rpt_$(SrvName).txt"
$EmailSubject="Server Disk Space Report for SrvName"
$EmailBody="Attached is the Server Disk Space Report SrvName"
$EmailAttachFile="C:\Svr_Win_Space_Rpt_$(SrvName).txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

When inserting variable into a string you can use like this: `"D:\Svr_Win_Space_Rpt_$(SrvName).txt"`